# How can I create a form-like interface in Mathematica, suitable for Mathematica Player?

Tags: output-formatting, interface, application

I want someting like:

f(x)=(imput field)

[Calculate] (button)

Result=(output field)

Comment: Free player is restricted to numerical input fields but other than that I do not foresee problems. Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Kuba I absolutely do not know how to do this.

Comment: Please see tutorial/CustomInterfaceConstructionOverview.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Clear["Golbal`*"];
x = 0; y = 0;
DoSomeCalculations[x_] := y = x^2;
InputField[Dynamic@x]
Dynamic@Button["Calculate", DoSomeCalculations[x]]
Print["output= ", Dynamic@y]
```